# Kivy button.bind() with a for loop binds buttons after loop finished

Tags: python, kivy

While trying to bind a button with a for loop, but the value is the last one in the for loop.

Code:

```py
def add(self):
    for i in range(10)
        button = Button(text="hello world")
        button.bind(on_release=(lambda dt: self.function(i)))
        self.add_widget(button)

def function(value):
    print(value)
```

When I click on any button, it prints out 9, however, when I press the first one, I want output to be 0, then 1, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in your code:

The local variable `i` is bound and updated in each loop iteration. In this case, the bug happens because `lambda dt: self.function(i)`, where `i` references the value of local `i` in each loop iteration. As this is defined in the scope of a loop, `i` will eventually end up at the last value in the iteration over `range(10)`, or `9` in this case.

For a simple fix, update your `lambda` definition to pass in the local variable `i` as a default parameter, thus copying the current value of `i` over to the `lambda` locals:

```
lambda dt, i=i: self.function(i)
```

#### Another Example

Here is yet another reproducible example where the output is similar to the example with the `for` loop you had posted - note that using a `list` comprehension as below is just a shorthand way of writing a `for` loop.

```py
>>> funcs = [lambda: i for i in range(5)]
>>> [f() for f in funcs]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Scoping the value of `i` to the lambda locals, fixes the bug that we notice in the above output:

```
>>> funcs = [lambda _i=i: _i for i in range(5)]
>>> [f() for f in funcs]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```